# "after" content in an <a> not clickable in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm using `after` content in CSS, but the content in `<a>` tag doesn't work as a link in Google Chrome (not clickable):

```
<a href="url"><label></label></a>

LABEL:after {content:"CLICK HERE"}
```

It works in Firefox. Is there any solution to this?

Check this out in chrome:

- http://jsfiddle.net/duuRk/ (not clickable)
- http://jsfiddle.net/HMn4d/ (works fine)

Comment: You're using `<label>` and pseudo content (before/after) incorrectly. Labels are for form controls and links should have non-empty content.

Comment: why is it incorrect? Anyway it's just a demonstration. not a real example.

Comment: I just told you in my previous comment. Even if it's just a demo, it's not a realistic one.

Comment: Anyway it must become clickable, because it's inside A. Firefox works correct. I works when rendered as inline-block

Comment: I absolutely agree that it's strange/unexpected behavior. Even with some content it still isn't clickable: http://jsfiddle.net/duuRk/2/

Comment: I checked out that too. Only the real content is clickable not the generated one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you give your 'a' tag the property display:inline-block it should work perfectly for you.

Comment: it worked, at least you saw the problem :))